# Can't find variable: FileTransfer on IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic2, file-transfer

I'm using the cordova's `FileTransfer` plugin with the `ionic-native` wrapper. The app runs successfully in iPhone simulator but when I run the app in my mobile device I get the error in the console as:

`ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: FileTransfer` with some stack trace.

**Findings:**

- The app runs without any issue on Android devices
- Reseting ionic state has no effect
- Entering `FileTransfer` in console returns its object. So, it is clear that it has been initialized
- The app runs good when all the reference to that plugin are removed from the app, even though there are other plugins(camera & datepicker). So, only the `file-transfer` plugin creates the problem.
- Roughly 1 out of 10 times the app run in the device without any error but it crashes after restarting the app.

**Plugins used**

- `cordova-plugin-camera`
- `cordova-plugin-datepicker`
- `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`
- `cordova-plugin-whitelist`

**Specifications:**

- Simulator iPhone6/iOS 9.3
- Devices iPhone6/iOS 9.3.1 & iPhone4S/iOS 9.3.5
- Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
- Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
- Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
- ios-deploy version: 1.8.6
- ios-sim version: 5.0.8
- OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
- Node Version: v4.4.5
- Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014

**Code:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Transfer} from 'ionic-native';
@Injectable()
export class MyClass {
    fileTransfer = new Transfer();
    constructor(){
    }
    public upload (url: string, image: string, onProgress: any, opt?: any){
        let options = {
            fileKey: "file",
            mimeType: "image/png",
            chunkedMode: false
        }
        this.fileTransfer.onProgress(onProgress);
        return this.fileTransfer.upload(image, this.baseUrl + url, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share us the code where you use FileTransfer ? I believe you have this error because the plugin is not initiated when you call it. You need to use all plugins after platform.ready()

Comment: @e666 added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling all the plugins and just running `ionic run ios` command fixed this issue. Since the `ionic state reset` also does the same thing, this might be a problem with the CLI.